# Calling other existing smart TV applications from another application for Samsung Smart TV SDK

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I am using Samsung smart TV SDK for developing an app.

Is it possible to call an existing smart TV app from another app. It is possible in Android, is it also possible here? And if yes, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible if you know the widgetID of the application that you want to call. widgetID is number formatted string which you will get when you register your application to certification team.

But if you want to call the application that is not yours and you don't know the widgetID of the application then it's not possible.

http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00006/common_module_widget_object.html#ref00006-common-module-widget-object-runsearchwidget

Answer (score 0):

you may get success in loading other smarttv app by using location.href if that app is hosted on some server, this can be achieved in test environment as i have done it my self, But here are some issues of doing it,

when you will send app for Samsung QA, they will straight way refuse the app, as its strictly against their policy to use server redirection,

more ever the biggest issue is with the key codes, so far as per my experience with smart tv app, i can say that Samsung have the  different key codes then the other smart tv